# Actionscript, set objects invisible

Tags: actionscript-3

This is a script for when i click an object, it opens a small book with some page flip effect.

I'm done with almost everything but i want that when i click in a back button everything desapears and i go back to only seeing the original object. It is not working because its only deleting one of the pages! I tried doing an array but it didnt work either and Im not very good with arrays too. Can anyone help?

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;    
import fl.transitions.easing.*;    
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;    
import flash.display.Sprite;    
import flash.display.Loader;    
var cont : DisplayObject;    
var cont2 : DisplayObject;    
var imgLoader : Loader;

//loads pages    
for (var i:int=0; i<=4; i++){    
    imgLoader  = new Loader();    
    imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoadJPEG);     
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(""+i+".png"));    
}

var imgLoader2 : Loader;

//loads back button    
imgLoader2  = new Loader();    
imgLoader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoadSketch);     
imgLoader2.load(new URLRequest("voltaatrassketchbook.png"));

function onLoadJPEG (e : Event) : void {    
    cont = e.target.loader;    
    cont.x =250;    
    cont.y =50;    
    cont.width = (445-100)/2;    
    cont.height = (604-100)/2;    
    addChild(cont);    
    cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, FlipPage);    
}

function onLoadSketch (e : Event) : void {    
    cont2 = e.target.loader;     
    cont2.x =450;    
    cont2.y =300;
    cont2.width = 181/2;    
    cont2.height = 127/2;    
    addChild(cont2);    
    cont2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volta);
}

function FlipPage(e:MouseEvent):void{    
    setChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.currentTarget), this.numChildren - 1);    
    if (e.currentTarget.rotationY == 0) {    
        var myTween:Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "rotationY", 
            Regular.easeInOut,0, 180, 1, true);
    }

    if (e.currentTarget.rotationY == 180) {    
        var myTween:Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "rotationY", 
            Regular.easeInOut, 180, 0, 1, true);

    }

}

//function to go back    
function volta (e: MouseEvent): void  {    
    gotoAndStop(1);    
    cont.visible=false;    
    cont2.visible=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

You are right that you could use an array. Put this at the top of your code, before you start loading the pages:

```
var pages:Array = [];
```

Then put this as the final line inside `onLoadJPEG()`

```
pages.push(cont);
```

That will add each image to the array when it is loaded.

Then in `volta()` you can loop through the array and make each image invisible

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    DisplayObject(pages[i]).visible = false;
}
```

---

**Option 2**

Another approach would be to add all the images to a container Sprite and then all you would have to do is make the container Sprite invisible.

Add this to the top of your code before you load the pages :

```
var pages:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(pages);
```

Then in `onLoadJPEG()` add cont as a child of the container

```
pages.addChild(cont);
```

Then in `volta()` :

```
pages.visible = false;
```

If you use this approach, don't forget to call setChildIndex() on the container inside of `FlipPage()` :

```
pages.setChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.currentTarget), this.numChildren - 1);
```

Comment: Btw do you have any ideia how can i put the page blank when i flip it? When i flip it insted of getting white it shows the reflex of the page i just flipped.

Comment: @user2397976 You would need to create a container for each page that would contain the front image and the back image. Then you would need to check the rotation every frame. If the rotation was greater than 90 and less than 270, you would set the child index of the back image to numchildren - 1. If the rotation was greater than 270 or less than 90 you would set the child index of the front image to numchildren - 1. If you need more help understanding, ask this as a separate question, and I can give you a more thorough example.